# Is there a way to edit the maximum CPS in pynput?

Tags: python, pynput

So recently I've been using pynput and I have noticed that no matter the delay I set it as the maximum CPS with pynput is always 10 cps. Now in pyautogui you can edit the hard coded pause between clicks, but I was wondering if this is possible in pynput.
For example:

```
import pynput
from pynput.mouse import Button as btn
from pynput.mouse import Controller
import time

mouse = Controller()
delay = 0
mouse.click(btn.left)
time.sleep(delay)
```

No matter what you change the "delay" value to, the max CPS is always 10 with Pynput, and trying "pynput.PAUSE = 0.01" doesn't change the output.

Comment: What means CPS？ This seems to have nothing to do with vscode.

Comment: Like, there is a hard coded pause between clicks so that there is always 10 clicks per second (cps = clicks per second). I was wondering how I can change the pause between the clicks.